# Holding down backspace on iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, text-input

Holding down backspace on iPhone deletes about six characters per second.

However, after about three consecutive seconds of holding down backspace, entire words start disappearing by the pair at a rate of about three pairs per second!

How can I disable the "feature" that starts chomping two words at a time a few times per second when holding down backspace on my iPhone?

iOS 7.1.2, iPhone 5s

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to disable the fast delete. There is an undo command, however, for when you've deleted too much. When the keyboard is up, shake the phone. A popup asks if you want to undo.